# How to use Multithreading to effectively

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to do a task that I've already completed except this time using multithreading. I have to read a lot of data from a file (line by line), grab some information from each line, and then add it to a Map. The file is over a million lines long so I thought it may benefit from multithreading.

I'm not sure about my approach here since I have never used multithreading in Java before. 
I want to have the main method do the reading, and then giving the line that has been read to another thread which will format a String, and then give it to another thread to put into a map.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Some information read from file
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = '';
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("somefile.txt"));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Pass line to another task
        }


    // Here I want to get a total from B, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that

}


public class Parser extends Thread
{
    private Mapper m1;

    // Some reference to B
    public Parse (Mapper m) {
        m1 = m;
    }

    public parse (String s, int i) {
        // Do some work on S
        key = DoSomethingWithString(s);
        m1.add(key, i);
    }

}

public class Mapper extends Thread
{
    private SortedMap<String, Integer> sm;
    private String key;
    private int value;
    boolean hasNewItem;

    public Mapper() {
        sm = new TreeMap<String, Integer>;
        hasNewItem = false;
    }

    public void add(String s, int i) {
        hasNewItem = true;
        key = s;
        value = i;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                if (hasNewItem) {
                    // Find if street name exists in map
                    sm.put(key, value);
                    newEntry = false;
                }   
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        // I'm not sure how to give the Map back to main. 
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am taking the right approach. I also do not know how to terminate the Mapper thread and retrieve the map in the main. I will have multiple Mapper threads but I have only instantiated one in the code above.

I also just realized that my Parse class is not a thread, but only another class if it does not override the run() method so I am thinking that the Parse class should be some sort of queue.

And ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:
Thanks for all of the replies. It seems that since I/O will be the major bottleneck there would be little efficiency benefit from parallelizing this. However, for demonstration purpose, am I going on the right track? I'm still a bit bothered by not knowing how to use multithreading.

Comment: Reading from files is the bottle neck of your code. Multi-threading will not help here.

Comment: Using multi-threading can shoot you on your foot here. Your thread can run much faster than the Disk IO rate as @HovercraftFullOfEels  pointed out. How are you planning to manage which thread reads how many lines.What if one or more threads failed due to some unforeseen reason ? 

I'd recommend that you process one file in a single thread and choose a processing approach based on the machine at hand. If you have a server with 128 gigs of ram, read it into memory and then do the processing, if not process line by line.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you need multiple threads? You only have one disk and it can only go so fast. Multithreading it won't help in this case, almost certainly. And if it does, it will be very minimal from a user's perspective. Multithreading isn't your *problem*. Reading from a huge file is your bottle neck.

Comment: That's true, my biggest bottleneck will definitely be reading from the file. Would it help with speed to have one thread continually read from IO, while another does parsing and putting the items into the map?

Comment: For demonstration sakes, any improvements I could do with my approach above though? I understand that it wouldn't help much and it is probably not worth the trouble especially for production code, but I am still curious.

Answer (score 2):

Frequently I/O will take much longer than the in-memory tasks. We refer to such work as *I/O-bound*. Parallelism may have a marginal improvement at best, and can actually make things worse.

You certainly don't need a different thread to put something into a map. Unless your parsing is unusually expensive, you don't need a different thread for it either.

If you had other threads for these tasks, they might spend most of their time sitting around waiting for the next line to be read.

Even parallelizing the I/O won't necessarily help, and may hurt. Even if your CPUs support parallel threads, your hard drive might not support parallel reads.

**EDIT:**

All of us who commented on this assumed the task was probably I/O-bound -- because that's frequently true. However, from the comments below, this case turned out to be an exception. A better answer would have included the fourth comment below:

> Measure the time it takes to read all the lines in the file without processing them. Compare to the time it takes to both read and process them. That will give you a loose upper bound on how much time you could save. This may be decreased by a new cost for thread synchronization.

Comment: So the best would just be to do it all serially?

Comment: If you did get some improvement from separating the reading and processing into two threads, it's likely to be small, at the cost of more development time/risk and more complex code to maintain. That said, I'm not certain how our remarks about hard disk drives apply to solid-state drives (SSDs). Anyone else care to comment on parallelizing reads with SSDs?

Comment: For demonstration sakes, any improvements I could do with my approach above though? I understand that it wouldn't help much and it is probably not worth the trouble especially for production code, but I am still curious.

Comment: Measure the time it takes to read all the lines in the file *without processing them*. Compare to the time it takes to both read and process them. That will give you a loose upper bound on how much time you could save. This may be decreased by a new cost for thread synchronization. Even if you decided to go forward, I would encourage you strongly to *not* create a new thread whose sole purpose is putting items in a map.

Comment: In total, my time is around 9000 ms, just reading without any processing is 900 ms, so there is a bit of room for improvement. 

How about if I just have one other task for the string processing and map insertion?

Comment: Now I'm glad I qualified my answer with "unless your parsing is unusually expensive." With those times, your case may be an exception. First, double-check that you're measuring the time correctly. I see you're using a TreeMap rather than a HashMap. Do you specifically need a SortedMap, or is a HashMap sufficient? It may be worthwhile to make another measurement with reading/parsing but without map insertion. Whether three threads would be more useful than two depends on the measurement.

Comment: Unfortunately I am required to use a SortedMap and a TreeMap seems to be faster than a ConcurrentSkipListMap. 

Also when adding something to the map, I have to check if it already exists, and if it does I have to increment by value by (value += amount) which I did not include in my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to read [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law). Since the majority of your work is strictly serial (the IO) you will get negligible improvements by multi-threading the remainder. Certainly not worth the cost of creating watertight multi-threaded code.

Perhaps you should look for a new toy-example to parallelise.

Comment: I am in specific needs for using this example. Currently the entire program takes about 9000 ms to run, and reading the input line by line alone is 800 ms so I think I could see some improvement if I do parallelise it at least a little. I'm thinking of only using two threads, where one does the reading, and one does everything else.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code? It would be wise to work out where the time is being spend prior to attempting to optimise.